# How can I configure Buildkite to hide certain strings from the web UI?

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to configure Buildkite to filter certain strings from the output of the web UI. I remember reading in the Buildkite docs about how to tell the `buildkite-agent` about certain environment variables that should not be printed in the web UI, but can no longer find that information. Does that functionality still exist? Can anyone direct me to those docs?

**Background**

Buildkite (buildkite.com) is a Continuous Integration system that has agents running on local machines, and a web UI that shows the results of build output. We already filter keys from the output that we initiate, but would like another level of assurance that new commands will also have sensitive keys redacted from the output of the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do this myself now

According to https://buildkite.com/docs/agent/v3/cli-start you can pass in `redacted-vars` or `$BUILDKITE_REDACTED_VARS`

You also have to pass in env `$BUILDKITE_AGENT_EXPERIMENT` with value `output-redactor`